# Time Zone shows (null) with UTC+0 offsets on all timezones

Tags: timezone

I'm new to Linux and I'm having an issue with my clock showing the wrong time. When I pull up the Date & Time setting, my Time Zone shows

> (null) (Los Angeles, United States)

If I turn off Automatic Time Zone and pull up the world map, every timezone displays

> (null) (UTC+00) ...

If I click on the zone again, it updates with the correct timezone offset; however, the setting does not stay and eventually becomes null again. Entering `date` from the command-line shows the wrong time as well. `date +%Z` shows a blank. What can I check or run to resolve?

My system is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: That's a strange one but can you try running `timedatectl set-timezone America/Los_Angeles` and see if the setting persists after a reboot? No idea what's causing this though.